# Image resize Plugin for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, resize

I need a plugin in WOrdpress that would meets the following requirements-

I need a plgin where we can upload an image that appears behind the mask and can be moveable and scaleable.

The user can scale and move the images around how they like, once they are happy then we want to be able to download as a jpg.

So basically users need to upload there own picture, be able to move it around and scale behind the mask. Once they have finished download it to jpg.

Is their any plugin aroud in Wordpress?

Thanks in advance. Any help would appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: Optimize Images Resizing.

Comment: sorry friend i have to give users interface to customize image after uploading like scaling resizing to my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help you it seems to be what you wanted.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/vectr-embedded-graphics-editor/

Comment: i will have to add this feature for the user who will upload an image. I saw about this plugin in the youtube. How will I add this to frontend

Comment: Go check in the settings

Answer (score 0):

Try below plugins Hope this will help you,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/resize-image-after-upload/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a new powerful wordpress plugin which allow you to optimize compress images and speedup the site,Its totally free and no required to any kind of registration,its very promising,
Just see it here:   https://wordpress.org/plugins/way2enjoy-compress-images/